# Script/Filter Multi-line & Multi-field records, with variable number of lines

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

tldr; SAN CLI command emits horrid formatting that makes automation difficult. 
This formatting is fixed.

My Problem:
I'm trying to script the onlining and offlining of sheduled SAN snapshots, 
but the SAN CLI wraps text in inconvenient places.

The required output of the solution (per record) is two fields, 
Snapshot and Status, on a single line:

```
VolumeName-YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS.NNNN.N online/offline
VolumeName-YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS.NNNN.N online/offline
```

Note:
The VolumeName can have from 1 to 64 chars which results in 
a record having 2-4 lines
The Schedule can also be named, and have up to 64 characters 
which would then cause the record to be 8 lines.

Examples.

```
1. Real world
SAN-01> volume select hv01-200G show snapshots
Name                        Permission Status      Schedule Connections
--------------------------- ---------- ----------- -------- -----------
hv01-200G-2013-11-29-12:33: read-write offline              0
  54.1798.1
hv01-200G-2014-08-05-11:00: read-write offline     Site01 H 0
  00.9698.1                                          V Hour
                                                     ly

2. Longest possible volume name
SAN-01> volume select 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
567890123 show snapshots
Name                        Permission Status      Schedule Connections
--------------------------- ---------- ----------- -------- -----------
123456789012345678901234567 read-write offline              0
  8901234567890123456789012
  34567890123-2014-08-07-13
  :05:09.9761.1
123456789012345678901234567 read-write online               0
  8901234567890123456789012
  34567890123-2014-08-07-13
  :05:23.9762.1


3. Shortest volume name
SAN-01> volume select X show snapshots
Name                        Permission Status      Schedule Connections
--------------------------- ---------- ----------- -------- -----------
X-2014-08-07-13:10:35.9764. read-write offline              0
  1
X-2014-08-07-13:10:46.9765. read-write online               0
```

1

Can anyone help with a sensible solution - grep sed awk perl or 
anything else I can run on a linux box?

Cheers,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk does the trick:

```
awk '/(on|off)line/ { o[++c]=$3 } substr($0,0,27)~$1 { v[c]=v[c] $1 } END{ for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print v[i],o[i] }' file
```

**Explanation**

When the word on/offline is matched, increment the counter `c`, then create and save the state to the array `o`. As long as there is something in the first column (i.e. the first field on the line matches the first 27 characters on the line), add to the volume data information. Once the file has been processed, print out the corresponding items of both arrays.

**Testing it out**

real:

```
$ awk '/(on|off)line/ { o[++c]=$3 } substr($0,0,27)~$1 { v[c]=v[c] $1 } END{ for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print v[i],o[i] }' real    
hv01-200G-2013-11-29-12:33:54.1798.1 offline
hv01-200G-2014-08-05-11:00:00.9698.1 offline
```

longest:

```
$ awk '/(on|off)line/ { o[++c]=$3 } substr($0,0,27)~$1 { v[c]=v[c] $1 } END{ for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print v[i],o[i] }' longest 
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123-2014-08-07-13:05:09.9761.1 offline
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123-2014-08-07-13:05:23.9762.1 online
```

shortest:

```
$ awk '/(on|off)line/ { o[++c]=$3 } substr($0,0,27)~$1 { v[c]=v[c] $1 } END{ for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print v[i],o[i] }' shortest 
X-2014-08-07-13:10:35.9764.1 offline
X-2014-08-07-13:10:46.9765.1 online
```

---

By the way, you mentioned that you were having some trouble using this script with mawk. I believe that the reason why is the regular expression at the beginning. mawk doesn't suppose extended regular expressions, so you have to make some adjustments:

```
$ mawk '/\(on\|off\)line/ { o[++c]=$3 } substr($0,0,27)~$1 { v[c]=v[c] $1 } END{ for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print v[i],o[i] }' real
```

should work. Note that I may be wrong as I haven't got mawk to test with but I did observe this behaviour using grep:

```
$ grep '(on|off)line' real                             # doesn't work
$ grep -E '(on|off)line' real                          # works (extended regexp)
hv01-200G-2013-11-29-12:33: read-write offline              0
hv01-200G-2014-08-05-11:00: read-write offline     Site01 H 0
$ grep '\(on\|off\)line' real                          # also works
hv01-200G-2013-11-29-12:33: read-write offline              0
hv01-200G-2014-08-05-11:00: read-write offline     Site01 H 0
```

Comment: Hi Tom, initially your awk script produced different results for me. After some poking around it became apparent that the awk supplied with my OS (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS) was actually mawk. After installing gawk, your script works perfectly. Thankyou not just for the solution, but also the explanation!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I've added to my answer, I think it should work for mawk now as well.